# SVG Elements Capped at 100k?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, svg, gdi

I am trying to generate an SVG file with nearing 1M elements and I am finding that the file caps is created correctly but the rendering is capped at 100K elements. I'm guessing this is some kind of fundamental limit imposed by the rendering engine (I'm using IE to render the SVG).

I am using SVGNet http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge to generate the SVG from GDI objects in C#.

Is there a way I can exceed the 100K element count while still using SVG? Is there a better format I could be using with C# (perhaps WPF) that will still be vectorised?

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Cheers,
Danny

Comment: How can you possibly make sense of a diagram with 100K elements on it. The right solution is surely to render fewer elements.

Comment: With great difficulty ;-)

This is for a scientific application where it is necessary to both look at macroscopic and microscopic interactions within a single result file (the SVG output).

You are correct though, what I should be doing is redrawing at different levels of detail much like a 3D game engine does for draw distance. Unfortunately this is a bit beyond my technical capability.